# DataGridView without selected row at the beginning

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In my WinForms I have `DataGridView`. I wanted to select full row at once so I set `SelectionMode` as `FullRowSelect`. And now I have problem, because at the beginning my form underlines first row (set of selected rows is empty, the first row is not selected but just underlined). I have tried many things, such as:

```
    private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

And all failed, because in fact there is no selection.

How can I get rid of this underline?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you are manually adding the rows, Clear selection after adding all the rows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately none of these answers helped me, but I found other solution. Instead of unable selection I will just hide it with this piece of code:

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
```

So if anyone just wants to hide the selection it's gonna work pretty well.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 20):

Just put `dataGridView1.ClearSelection();` in load event of the form.

Answer (score 17):

This works for me:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. As I said first row is not selected it is just underlined.

Comment: This probably is due to the row having focus. You could try to give the focus to a different control with the `focus()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to put in Shown event `datagridView.ClearCelection()` and also `datagridView.CurrentCell=null` and for example if you want to select row for deleting or changing informations just do `if(datagridView.CurrentCell==null){
MessageBox.Show("You must select row");}` it works for me

Comment: This works for me too!
If you put the ClearSelection method call in OnLoad event handler instead of OnShown as I did, ClearSelection will somewhy work only once (at the first time you load the form).

Answer (score 2):

Try This may be helpful

```
private void dgv_order_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            dgv_order.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
            dgv_order.ClearSelection();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting  `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false` in constructor after `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: It works :) The only thing I have to consider is write this line of code in Shown event. When I wrote this in my constructor, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can call dataGridView.ClearSelection() method inside form_Load event like this...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // You will get selectedCells count 1 here
     DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection selectedCells = dataGridView.SelectedCells;
     // Call clearSelection 
     dataGridView.ClearSelection();
     // Now You will get selectedCells count 0 here
     selectedCells = dataGridViewSchedule.SelectedCells;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me for clear selection on databind

```
Protected Sub GridCancel_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridCancel.DataBinding
    GridCancel.SelectedIndex = -1

End Sub
```

Comment: It's possible what it works... But here the question is related to Winforms `Datagridview`, not ASP.NET `GridView`, so the answer is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The event to set for disabled selected row at start is this,
and manage a FLAG to stop the ClearSelection

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (FLAG==true)
    {
       dataGridView.ClearSelection();
       FLAG=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you reload your form without closing your program, the first row will be highlighted. But it will not be selected, and you will get -1 for selected row index.

You can do it just like this:

1. Store default styles when the form is loading:

```
 Public Class aRoots
    Dim df1, df2, df3, df4 As Color
    Private Sub aRoots_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            df1 = DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor
            df2 = DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
            df3 = DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor
            df4 = DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor
```

2. Change cell styles when interacting with datagridview:

```
Private Sub LoadRoot()
       For i = 0 To 5
                DGV_Root.Rows.Add()
                For j = 0 To 3
                    DGV_Root.Item(j, i).Value = ...
                Next
            Next
        'DGV_Root.ClearSelection() ==> instead of this use 2 lines below
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = df2
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = df4
    End Sub
```

3. Change cell styles to default when selection is being changed like cell_click or cell_double click:

```
Private Sub DGV_Root_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DGV_Root.CellMouseClick
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = df1
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = df3


...
End Sub
```

4. restore all to default when u want to close form:

```
Private Sub PbClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PbClose.Click
        BtnCancel.PerformClick()
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = df1
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = df2
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = df3
        DGV_Root.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = df4
        Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Hope this help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

If this is because it raised unwanted GridView1_SelectionChanged event on initial loading, you can use a flag to handle this

```
public partial class YourFormName
{ 
    private bool IsReady= false;

    private void YourFormName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
           //Load your GridView1...
           //Format your GridView1...
            IsReady = true;
    }
    void GridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!IsReady) 
             return;
         //do the rest of the stuffs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**"Shown"** event that run after frame first displayed worked for me:

```
private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation, "`dataGridView.Shown`" event was the only solution that worked like magic for me:

```
// Clears the default selection of both Data Grid Views
private void dataGridView_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView.ClearSelection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public void Reset()

{

dataGridView.ClearSelection();

}

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late but I am almost with a very suitable solution to your question,
so all you have to do is add a "timer" set it to ENABLE in the TICK method disable the timer and then put the DGV.ClearSelection(); keep the timer interval to 100

e.g

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled= false;
        DGV.ClearSelection();
    }
```

tada Problem solved and the selection still works fine later.