# How to move selection from my row in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried with calling `dataGridView.ClearSelection();` in my Load and Shown event and it just hide selection marker but anyway the first row is selected ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to happen.

Comment: I want to deselect row in my datagridView

Comment: It works for me, so it's not clear why it doesn't work for you.  Post code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: It removes selection marker but if you have delete button it deletes first anyway which means selection is still on first item did you try that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView without selected row at the beginning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879461/datagridview-without-selected-row-at-the-beginning)

Comment: DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the current cell to null:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnShown(e);
  dataGridView.ClearSelection();
  dataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
}
```

Comment: I tried like that but when I want to check `dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index<0` I got an error, exception

Comment: @jhony3 Of course, because now CurrentRow is null, so it doesn't have an available Index property to check.

Comment: Ok i did it like that it work and I check value with `if(dataGrdiView.CurrentCell==null){MessageBox.Show("You must select the row};`

Comment: @jhony3 As you said, it worked. This post contains exactly what you asked for. If you have any other question about other parts of your application, it's better to accept and upvote this post and then ask a new question :)

Comment: I was upvoting this one but I didn't have rating I swear it helped me for sure as I wrote I pressed for 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void dataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender,  DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = false;
}
```